$E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$ implies $X\perp Y$ when $X$ and $Y$ take only two values
I have the next problem:
Problem. Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables each taking only two values. If $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$, then $X$ and $Y$ are independent.
I have tried to get a proof but I haven't be able, this is what I've tried
Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be the values which take $X$ and let $y_1$ and $y_2$ be the values which take $Y$. We know that
\begin{align*}
E(XY)&={{x_1y_1P(XY{\,=\,}x_1y_1)+x_1y_2P(XY{\,=\,}x_1y_2)}\\+{x_2y_1P(XY{\,=\,}x_2y_1)+x_2y_2P(XY{\,=\,}x_2y_2)}}\\[1ex]&={{x_1y_1P(X{\,=\,}x_1, Y{\,=\,}y_1)+x_1y_2P(X{\,=\,}x_1, Y{\,=\,}y_2)}+{x_2y_1P(X{\,=\,}x_2,\ Y{\,=\,}y_1)+x_2y_2P(X{\,=\,}x_2, Y{\,=\,}y_2)}}
\end{align*}
and we also know that
$$
E(X)=x_1P(X=x_1)+x_2P(X=x_2)\\
E(Y)=y_1P(Y=y_1)+y_2P(Y=y_2),
$$
then
$$\begin{align}
E(X)E(Y)&={{x_1y_1P(X=x_1)P(Y=y_1)+x_1y_2P(X=x_1)P(Y=y_2)}+{x_2y_1P(X=x_2)P(Y=y_1)+x_2y_2P(X=x_2)P(Y=y_2)}}\end{align}
$$
Since $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$, then
$$\begin{align}
{~~{{x_1y_1P(X=x_1, Y=y_1)+x_1y_2P(X=x_1, Y=y_2)}+{x_2y_1P(X=x_2, Y=y_1)+x_2y_2P(X=x_2, Y=y_2)}}\\={{x_1y_1P(X=x_1)P(Y=y_1)+x_1y_2P(X=x_1)P(Y=y_2)}+{x_2y_1P(X=x_2)P(Y=y_1)+x_2y_2P(X=x_2)P(Y=y_2),}}}
\end{align}$$
here is where I am sunk, I can't see how the last implies $X$ and $Y$ are independent, if we know that $x_i,y_i\geq 0$, then it happens, but that condition is not given.
Can anyone help me please?

First look at the special case where $X$ and $Y$ take the values $0$ and $1,$ i.e., they are Bernoulli variables. Write $p$ and $q$ for their expectations. We have
$$P[X=1\wedge Y=1]=P[XY=1]=E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]=pq=P[X=1]P[Y=1]$$
$$P[X=1\wedge Y=0]=P[X(1-Y)=1]=E[X(1-Y)]=E[X-XY]=E[X]-E[X]E[Y]=p(1-q)=P[X=1]P[Y=0]$$
$$P[X=0\wedge Y=1]=P[(1-X)Y=1]=E[(1-X)Y]=(1-p)q=P[X=0]P[Y=1]$$
$$P[X=0\wedge Y=0]=P[(1-X)(1-Y)=1]=E[(1-X)(1-Y)]=(1-p)(1-q)=P[X=0]P[Y=0]$$
In the general case set $\tilde X=(X-x_1)/(x_2-x_1)$ and $\tilde Y=(Y-y_1)/(y_2-y_1).$ Clearly $X$ and $Y$ are independent iff $\tilde X$ and $\tilde Y$ are, but we know that these are Bernoulli variables and direct computation gives that $E[\tilde X\tilde Y]=E[\tilde X]E[\tilde Y].$

One way to show this that is less elementary but perhaps offers some insight is that $X$ and $Y$ are independent if $\mathbf{E}[f(X) g(Y)] = \mathbf{E}f(X) \cdot \mathbf{E}g(Y)$ for all continuous and bounded $f$ and $g$.
Notice that condition that $\mathbf{E}(XY) = \mathbf{E}X \cdot \mathbf{E}Y$ is equivalent to that equality holding for linear $f$ and $g$.
But notice that if $X$ only takes two points, then $f$ will coincide with a linear function on those points.
Indeed, for $x \in \{x_1, x_2\}$.
$$
f(x)
= f(x_1)\frac{x - x_2}{x_1 - x_2} + f(x_2)\frac{x - x_1}{x_2 - x_1}.
$$
Thus, for any continuous bounded $f$ and $g$, there are constants $a, b, c, d$ such that $f(X) = aX + b$ and $g(Y) = cY + d$, from which
$$
\mathbf{E}[f(X)g(Y)]
= \mathbf{E}[(aX + b)(cY + d)]
= \mathbf{E}(aX + b) \cdot \mathbf{E}(cY + d)
= \mathbf{E}f(X) \cdot \mathbf{E}g(Y),
$$
from which $X$ and $Y$ are independent.
